# Tweeting from .NET suddenly throws exception

Tags: .net, twitter

I have a .NET application which has been generating tweets happily for years, but has suddenly (June 2013) started throwing this exception:

*Exception of type 'TwitterAPIException' was thrown.*

I've read another StackOverflow thread which suggests that the problem might be that I need to escape punctuation characters, so I've rewritten the tweet to exclude any unusual characters.  I've tried in IE and Firefox.

At the heart of my code is this (I've missed out various constructors to show the lines to do with Twitter):

```
Private ConsumerKey As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConsumerKey")
Private ConsumerKeySecret As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ConsumerKeySecret")
Private AccessToken As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AccessToken")
Private AccessTokenSecret As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AccessTokenSecret")


Private Twitter As New TwitterAPI

    'authenticate with Twitter and send
    Twitter.AuthenticateWith(ConsumerKey, ConsumerKeySecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret)

  Try

        'send the tweet
        Twitter.Update(Message)
```

Anyone any idea what's happening?  We tweet once every couple of days on average, and it's all useful and relevant stuff, so there is absolutely no reason that I can see for Twitter to block our account.

Comment: Eight months on, I have a different answer - see this [separate SO question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455601/tweeting-using-api-1-1-suddenly-not-working-january-2014-ssl-tls

Answer (score 2):

Probably where they shut down the 1.0 API. https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

You need to move to 1.1 ASAP.

(it bit us a few days ago too, which is how I knew about it)

Comment: That sounds very plausible!  If I find out more about how to transition, I'll try to remember to post it here.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Aaargh!  All I want to do is to tweet from VB!  Twitterizer seems to be no longer supported, and tweetsharp (and all the others I've found) seem way too complicated.  Is there no simple solution?

Comment: The Twitterizer source code is open, and I don't believe that there would be a lot of work required to update it from 1.0 of the API to 1.1.

Comment: After much resource, it seems like Twitter don't publish a simple DLL any more to link to!  We're now writing our own code to authenticate with Twitter and send a message, and may blog about it when written.  But surely it can't be this hard?

Answer (score 0):

Two months on, I have an answer!  This [excellent post](http://www.overpie.com/aspnet/articles/csharp-post-message-to-twitter.cshtml) gives a nice simple standalone C# class for people like me who just want to get the code working, and don't really mind what it does.  I also found [this blog](http://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/16/oauth-timestamps-and-nonces/) useful to explain what was happening behind the scenes.

Since our ASP.NET website is written using VB, I tried translating the OverPie code into VB, but I just couldn't get it to work properly.  In the end I gave up and created a C# class library, and referenced this instead.

I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Eight months on, I have a different answer now, which SO is forcing me to add as a comment - see Eight months on, I have a different answer - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455601/tweeting-using-api-1-1-suddenly-not-working-january-2014-ssl-tls .